# Embedding flash Wimpy player so that it works in Firefox

Tags: flash, firefox, embed, wimpy

Can somebody help me getting Wimpy player to work in Firefox? I followed the guide from [Wimpy documentation page](http://wimpyplayer.com/docs/mp3/insert.html.html) and am still getting nowhere.

For tests, I used the same HTML code to embed different swf file and it works perfectly. Could it be the SWF file corrupted itself? Then why it works fine on IE?

[Here is a test HTML code](http://www.blastbeat.tv/test.html) with two flash objects. The left one is Wimpy and the other is just an example. Currently only the right one shows up.

This is the code I use to embed it:

```
<object width="185" height="292" id="wimpy" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,47,0">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<param name="allownetworking" value="all"></param>
<param name="movie" value="http://www.blastbeat.tv/upload/mp3s/wimpy.swf"></param>
<param name="loop" value="false"></param>
<param name="menu" value="false"></param>
<param name="quality" value="high"></param>
<param name="scale" value="noscale"></param>
<param name="align" value="center"></param>
<param name="salign" value="lt"></param>
<param name="bgcolor" value="ffffff"></param>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
<param name="flashvars" value="wimpyApp=http://www.blastbeat.tv/upload/mp3s/wimpy.sql.ed.php&wimpySkin=http://www.blastbeat.tv/upload/mp3s/skin_blackpod8.xml&useMysql=yes&queryValue=21&queryWhere=user_id&startPlayingOnload=no&randomOnLoad=yes&loopPlaylist=all&popUpHelp=no&trackPlays=http://www.blastbeat.tv/upload/mp3s/trackscript.php&scrollInfoDisplay=yes"></param>
<embed width="185" height="292" scale="noscale" src="http://www.blastbeat.tv/upload/mp3s/wimpy.swf"
    allowscriptaccess="always"
    allownetworking="all"
    loop="false"
    menu="false"
    quality="high"
    scale="noscale"
    align="center"
    salign="lt"
    bgcolor="ffffff"
    wmode="transparent"
    flashvars="wimpyApp=http://www.blastbeat.tv/upload/mp3s/wimpy.sql.ed.php&wimpySkin=http://www.blastbeat.tv/upload/mp3s/skin_blackpod8.xml&useMysql=yes&queryValue=21&queryWhere=user_id&startPlayingOnload=no&randomOnLoad=yes&loopPlaylist=all&popUpHelp=no&trackPlays=http://www.blastbeat.tv/upload/mp3s/trackscript.php&scrollInfoDisplay=yes"
    name="wimpy"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
></embed>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that Wimpy player version I used was slightly outdated and wouldn't work with Flash 10. This is from their support page:

> Only the latest version of Wimpy
>   products work with Flash plugin
>   version 10.
>
> Older versions of Wimpy will no longer
>   work for users who have upgraded their
>   Flash Plugin to version 10. This is
>   due to the plugin being more strict
>   with respect to the way that
>   Actionscript code is interpreted
>   within the player.

Upgrade from minor version number is free. After upgrading Wimpy is back again in operation.

Answer (score 1):

I would very much recommend using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), that takes care of detecting the flash player, embedding the proper code for that browser and gives you a nice way to provide fallback content. Also, it'll look alot cleaner in your code!

Like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>SWFObject dynamic embed - step 3</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0");
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myContent">
      <p>Alternative content</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```